# Kill or execute javascript based on browser width

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, jquery-events, flexslider, browser-detection

In a nutshell, I'd like to run a script (Flexslider in this case) only when the browser window is below a specific size.

i.e.

*Less than* 480px wide (either at launch or on resize) - run Flexslider

*More than* 480px wide (either at launch or on resize) - kill Flexslider and display list items as 'static' blocks/page elements

At the moment, I have the following code which works (to a degree) by using addClass and removeClass, based on browser width. However it requires a browser refresh in order to kill or execute the script where relevant. As you've probably guessed, I'm no JS expert, however I'd be keen to hear your ideas.

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="foo">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li><img src="images/image1.jpg" width="320" height="320" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/image2.jpg" width="320" height="320" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/image3.jpg" width="320" height="320" alt=""></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var pageWidth = $(window).width();
            if (pageWidth <= 480) {
                $("#foo").addClass('flexslider');
                   $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                       animation: "slide",
                       directionNav: true
                    });
            }
        $(window).resize(function() {
            if ($(window).width() > 480) {
                $("#foo").removeClass('flexslider');
            }
            });
        });
```

---

**JS - revision 1**

```
     $(window).resize(function(){
        var windowWidth  = $(window).width();
        if (windowWidth  <= 480) {
            $("#foo").addClass('flexslider');
               $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                   animation: "slide",
                   directionNav: true
                });
        }
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() > 480) {
            $("#foo").removeClass('flexslider');
        }
        });
    });
```

---

**JS - revision 2**

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() >= 480) {
            $("#foo").removeClass('flexslider');
        }
        if ($(window).width() < 480) {
            $("#foo").addClass('flexslider');
            $('#foo').flexslider({animation: "slide"});
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Take

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() >= 480) {
            $("#foo").removeClass('flexslider');
        }
        if ($(window).width() < 480) {
            $("#foo").addClass('flexslider');
        }
    });
```

out of `$(document).ready` function.

What's happening is that document.ready is only firing when the page is loaded. if you want the window.ready function to fire after the page is resized it has to be taken out of the document.ready function

Also you'll need to do the same thing in both functions. or have a separate function that handles adding and removing the flexslider and have `window.resize` and `document.ready` call that function. the second way is possibly better.

hope that helps.

Comment: I would move the code to a defined function and call that function when the page is loaded or resized, or it won't run on pageload.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Well I'm kinda halfway there. If I resize from a large (960px wide) window down to 480px, it indeed fires Flexslider, however Flexslider still remains when I try and increase back up to 960px wide. Added my revisions above...

Comment: Thanks for your continued help, @eric.

Tried the above revision 2, which fires up Flexslider when the browser is reduced to 480px wide, however Flexslider still remains fired up once you try to resize above 480px... also, if the browser is *already* at 480px (or below), Flexslider won't fire up til the browser is resized.